# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 - Error in parsing Apex Response in salesforce LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get List of Object Apex controller method to LWC component. Apex controller creates one simple List of Object. And I imported apex controller method on my LWC component .js file and displaying on html file. The error is showing in console `Failed to load resource` like the following,

[image]

And my Apex controller code is like the following,

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<String> getCountry() {

    SObjectField pickGlobalCountryList = SObjectType.Blood_Donor__c.fields.Country__c.getSObjectField();
    List<PicklistEntry> countryList = 
    pickGlobalCountryList.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    
    List<String> globalCountry = new List<String>();  
    for(PicklistEntry objCtry: countryList) {
         globalCountry.add(objCtry.getValue());
    }
    return globalCountry;
  }
```

And I Imported in my .js file and wired using the following method in .js file,'

```
country = [];

@wire(getCountry)
result({ error, data }) {
if(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }
else if (data) {
    this.country = data.map((value) => {
        return {
            label: value,
            value
        };
    });
   }
  }
```

Html file,

```
    <td scope="col">
       <lightning-combobox
          name="Country"
          label="Country"
          options={country}
          placeholder="Search Country">
       </lightning-combobox>
    </td>
```

And the result  I am trying to add in combo box in html. But still showing Failed to load resource with internal server error. Can please anyone try to suggest modification or any good documentation reference please?

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces in this line `@wire(getCountry,{})` means that you're passing an object to the `getCountry` method, but in Apex it has been defined with no input parameter, so you should change it to `@wire(getCountry)`.

Moreover, if you would like to use the list returned by that method as options for a [combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation), it should hold objects with both `label` and `value` properties.
You could either create a custom Apex type (i.e. `ComboboxOption`) and return a list of that type, instead of returning a list of Object or return a list of String (the one you're returning now) and handle it in the wired function leveraging [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
@wire(getCountry)
fetchCountry({ error, data }) {
    if(error){
        console.log('getCountry', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    else if (data) {
        this.country = data.map((value) => {
            return {
                label: value,
                value
            };
        });
    }
}
```

In this case the Apex method should be:

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<String> getCountry() {
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> countryList = Blood_Donor__c.Country__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    List<String> globalCountries = new List<String>();

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry entry : countryList) {
        globalCountries.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    return globalCountries;
}
```

---

The attribute `options` is required for [combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification), moreover `country` has no `value` property since it's an array, so the HTML should be:

```html
<td scope="col">
    <lightning-combobox
        name="Country"
        label="Country"
        options={country}
        placeholder="Search Country">
    </lightning-combobox>
</td>
```

By the way, the error "Failed to load resource" is not the output of your console.log(), please change it to `console.log('getCountry', JSON.stringify(error));` to see the right error message.

Be sure to [grant the access](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_apex_access.htm&type=5) to that Apex class to the right profiles.

Comment: Thank you for your response. According to suggestion I modified, But still getting the same error. I updated the question and screenshot.

Comment: @Mr.DevEng There is an issue in the HTML part, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Class and html file modified according to your modified answer. And also checked class has access. But still error is there ? Is there anything went wrong in my implementation? I updated the codes above.